# How do I display custom tables field value in content-type form?

Tags: nodes

I have created custom table where am storing some information.

Now I want to show some data from that table to my particular content type form.

So how to do that?

What i did:

I have created one **custom table** which contains some history of form submissons. Now, whenever I come **on form want to show records from that cusom table**, show how to do that?

Comment: very broad question. show your efforts

Comment: @BhavikShah what i did, i have created one custom table which contains some history of form submitions, now whenever i come on form want to show records from that cusom table,show how to do that?

Comment: We don't have a code writing service here, please edit the question to include the code you're using, along with descriptions of the expected results, the actual results, error messages you're receiving, etc

Comment: @Clive still i havent made any code here,am still doing R&D how to do this? how to dispaly custom tables record on content type node add/edit form?

Comment: is there any hook available to display data in the form?

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck? This is a Q+A site for _specific_ questions about Drupal configuration/development - we're not going to tutor you through every part of the API that's involved in this in a single question. Please break your tasks down into individual ones (how do I use custom code to get data from a database? how can I format arbitrary data in a table? how can I alter an existing form to add some markup? etc), and do some research on each separately. I guarantee you that everything you need to know is already on this site somewhere, you just need to do the leg work to find it

Comment: @Clive yeah you are right, now i wanted to know  how can I alter an existing form to add some markup?